# Requesting additional permission on new sdk, but dialog shows login form

Tags: permissions, facebook-android-sdk

In previous android SDK, I asked new permission by calling `Facebook.authorize()` and it showed approving permission screen. But in SDK 3.0, when I call `FacebookActivity.openSessionForPublish()` , dialog always shows login form. How can I show approving permission screen?

I've set up session that has token and expiration date and its SessionState is `CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED` .

Is there any requirement for showing permission dialog or does `Facebook.authorize()` always show login form? Then please teach me right method for that.

My code is like below

```
 public class FbConn extends FacebookActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       if( savedInstanceState == null ) {
          Session savedSession = CommonUtil.getFbSession(CustomSessionStore.getFbInfo(getApplicationContext())); //get access token and expiration date from session store and set up new session.
          Session.setActiveSession(savedSession); 
          setSession(savedSession);
       }

    }

    protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       openSessionForPublish(EpisodeApplication.config.getSelectedServer().fbAppId, Constants.FB_PERMISSIONS);
    }

 }
```

**Update**

I've commented out these lines and permission request screen showed successfully. But I don't sure this is right way or not.

In `com.facebook.LoginActivity` line 62,

```
Utility.clearFacebookCookies(this);
```

In `com.facebook.Session` line 1202,

```
Utility.clearFacebookCookies(getStaticContext());
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the problem is.  Are you saying that every time you start your app the login dialog shows up even though the user has already been authenticated?

Comment: @JesseChen thanks. I've updated question. I have no problem using stored session. But when app ask additional facebook permission, new SDK always shows up login form (not permission check screen) even session has valid token information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have a valid session, from a previous auth flow, then if you want to request new permissions then use the Session.ReauthorizeRequest class.

```
Session.ReauthorizeRequest reauthRequest = new Session
                .ReauthorizeRequest(this, Constants.FB_PERMISSIONS);
session.reauthorizeForPublish(reauthRequest);
```

This should show a permissions screen for the new permissions you're asking for instead of the login form.

However, from looking at your logic it is not clear where you're handling the first time login. If you expect to handle it in this class then I suggest using the following:

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true);
```

This will open up a login form if there is no cached token. If there is a cached token, it will create a new Session and make it active. This will open a session with basic permissions (if the user needs to log in) or open a session with the permissions based on the cached token retrieved. You can then call the re-auth methods to ask for publish permissions. You'll want to do that in context and typically do not want to call call the auth functions back to back, i.e. log the user in, then immediately ask for publish permissions.

Comment: great. It works perfectly. As I request custom permissions, your suggestion does not fit me well. But it is very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no class Session.ReauthorizeRequest in the latest Facebook v3 SDK.

Comment: Yes, that method was for 3.0 beta. See https://developers.facebook.com/android/change-log-3.x/. ReauthorizeRequest was renamed to to NewPermissionsRequest.